# Is there a way to put a C++/winRT runtime class in a folder not the root project? in Visual Studio

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I know it seems to be a dummb question, but i have tried put a clas in folder inside the root project and I can not figure out how to solve broken paths in the files generated automaticly. For example I have a TitleBar class inside the BaseLayout folder (BaseLayout/TitleBar) then althought I have write the right include in my .cpp and .h files when I see the TitleBar.g.h file in the "Generated Files" folder (root/Generated Files/TitleBar.g.h) it refers to wrong xaml generated file "TitleBar.xaml.g.h" when the right apointment would be "BaseLayout/TitleBar.xaml.g.h"

```
#if defined(WINRT_FORCE_INCLUDE_TITLEBAR_XAML_G_H) || __has_include("TitleBar.xaml.g.h")
#include "TitleBar.xaml.g.h"
```

if I change this piece of code to "BaseLayout/TitleBar.xaml.g.h" it compiles correcly but i will need to do it ervery time a recompile all the solution, is there some way to config it?

the folder of the project:

[image]

Comment: Project > Properties > C/C++ > General > "Additional Include Directories" setting, add BaseLayout